# Why 3 equal symbols in boolean comparisons?

Tags: javascript, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Why do I see lots of javascript code lately with expressions that look like this:

```
if(val === "something")
```

Why "===" instead of just "=="?  What's the difference?  When should I use one or the other?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Comment: @mjv, did you mean recursion? :P

Comment: My.. I guess it's a duplicate of a duplicate...  Mathew, remember do check SO (and elsewhere) before posting a new question.  Thanks!

Comment: @Brandon!  LOL... must have cut/pasted the wrong url ;-)

Comment: I was wondering if there were duplicates.  What's interesting is i searched SO on "===" and didn't get any results.

Comment: In fairness to you, Matthew, finding tokens with non-letter/digit characters, such as "===" is not easy to do on most search engines, including on SO.

Answer (score 9):

The === does not allow type coercion, so something like this would return false:

```
if (2 === '2') // false
```

The "normal" javascript == operator does allow type coercion, and so this would return true:

```
if (2 == '2') // true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = 3;
var b = "3";

if (a == b) {
  // this is true.
}

if (a === b) {
  // this is false.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`===` is typically referred to as the identity operator. Values being compared must be of the same type and value to be considered equal. `==` is typically referred to as the equality operator and performs type coercion to check equality.

An example

```
1 == '1' // returns true even though one is a number, the other a string

1 === '1' // returns false. different datatypes
```

Doug Crockford touches briefly on this in [JavaScript the Good Parts google tech talk video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook). Worth spending an hour to watch.

Answer (score 0):

Checks that the type as well as the values match.  This is important since (0 == false) is true but (0 === false) is not true.